How to detect when a handle to my process is opened with OpenProcess from a foreign process?
I have this code to get all handle of some process by PID using NtQuerySystemInformation()
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cassert>

#define NT_SUCCESS(x) ((x) >= 0)
#define STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH 0xc0000004

#define SystemHandleInformation 16
#define ObjectBasicInformation 0
#define ObjectNameInformation 1
#define ObjectTypeInformation 2

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* _NtQuerySystemInformation)(
    ULONG SystemInformationClass,
    PVOID SystemInformation,
    ULONG SystemInformationLength,
    PULONG ReturnLength
    );

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* _NtDuplicateObject)(
    HANDLE SourceProcessHandle,
    HANDLE SourceHandle,
    HANDLE TargetProcessHandle,
    PHANDLE TargetHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    ULONG Attributes,
    ULONG Options
    );
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* _NtQueryObject)(
    HANDLE ObjectHandle,
    ULONG ObjectInformationClass,
    PVOID ObjectInformation,
    ULONG ObjectInformationLength,
    PULONG ReturnLength
    );

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING
{
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING, * PUNICODE_STRING;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE
{
    ULONG ProcessId;
    BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
    BYTE Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE, * PSYSTEM_HANDLE;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
{
    ULONG HandleCount;
    SYSTEM_HANDLE Handles[1];
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, * PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;

typedef enum _POOL_TYPE
{
    NonPagedPool,
    PagedPool,
    NonPagedPoolMustSucceed,
    DontUseThisType,
    NonPagedPoolCacheAligned,
    PagedPoolCacheAligned,
    NonPagedPoolCacheAlignedMustS
} POOL_TYPE, * PPOOL_TYPE;

typedef struct _OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION
{
    UNICODE_STRING Name;
    ULONG TotalNumberOfObjects;
    ULONG TotalNumberOfHandles;
    ULONG TotalPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG TotalNonPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG TotalNamePoolUsage;
    ULONG TotalHandleTableUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterNumberOfObjects;
    ULONG HighWaterNumberOfHandles;
    ULONG HighWaterPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterNonPagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterNamePoolUsage;
    ULONG HighWaterHandleTableUsage;
    ULONG InvalidAttributes;
    GENERIC_MAPPING GenericMapping;
    ULONG ValidAccess;
    BOOLEAN SecurityRequired;
    BOOLEAN MaintainHandleCount;
    USHORT MaintainTypeList;
    POOL_TYPE PoolType;
    ULONG PagedPoolUsage;
    ULONG NonPagedPoolUsage;
} OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION, * POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION;

PVOID GetLibraryProcAddress(LPCSTR LibraryName, LPCSTR ProcName)
{
    return GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA(LibraryName), ProcName);
}



int wmain(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
    _NtQuerySystemInformation NtQuerySystemInformation{};
    {
        auto const p_proc{ GetLibraryProcAddress("ntdll.dll", "NtQuerySystemInformation") };
        assert(p_proc); // TODO handle error...
        static_assert(sizeof(_NtQuerySystemInformation) == sizeof(p_proc), "pointer size mismatch");
        memcpy(&NtQuerySystemInformation, &p_proc, sizeof(NtQuerySystemInformation)); // deep copy
    }
    _NtDuplicateObject NtDuplicateObject{};
    {
        auto const p_proc{ GetLibraryProcAddress("ntdll.dll", "NtDuplicateObject") };
        assert(p_proc); // TODO handle error...
        static_assert(sizeof(_NtDuplicateObject) == sizeof(p_proc), "pointer size mismatch");
        memcpy(&NtDuplicateObject, &p_proc, sizeof(NtDuplicateObject)); // deep copy
    }
    _NtQueryObject NtQueryObject{};
    {
        auto const p_proc{ GetLibraryProcAddress("ntdll.dll", "NtQueryObject") };
        assert(p_proc); // TODO handle error...
        static_assert(sizeof(_NtQueryObject) == sizeof(p_proc), "pointer size mismatch");
        memcpy(&NtQueryObject, &p_proc, sizeof(NtQueryObject)); // deep copy
    }

    NTSTATUS status;
    PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION handleInfo;
    ULONG handleInfoSize = 0x10000;
    ULONG pid;
    HANDLE processHandle;
    ULONG i;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: handles [pid]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pid = _wtoi(argv[1]);

    if (!(processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, FALSE, pid)))
    {
        printf("Could not open PID %d! (Don't try to open a system process.)\n", pid);
        return 1;
    }

    handleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)malloc(handleInfoSize);

    /* NtQuerySystemInformation won't give us the correct buffer size,
       so we guess by doubling the buffer size. */
    while ((status = NtQuerySystemInformation(
        SystemHandleInformation,
        handleInfo,
        handleInfoSize,
        NULL
    )) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
        handleInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)realloc(handleInfo, handleInfoSize *= 2);

    /* NtQuerySystemInformation stopped giving us STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH. */
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        printf("NtQuerySystemInformation failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < handleInfo->HandleCount; i++)
    {
        SYSTEM_HANDLE handle = handleInfo->Handles[i];
        HANDLE dupHandle = NULL;
        POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION objectTypeInfo;
        PVOID objectNameInfo;
        UNICODE_STRING objectName;
        ULONG returnLength;

        /* Check if this handle belongs to the PID the user specified. */
        if (handle.ProcessId != pid) {
           // printf("Error - handle of other process %lu!\n", handle.ProcessId);
            continue;
        }

        /* Duplicate the handle so we can query it. */
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtDuplicateObject(processHandle, (HANDLE)handle.Handle,GetCurrentProcess(), &dupHandle, 0, 0, 0)))
        {
            //printf("[%#x] Error!\n", handle.Handle);
            continue;
        }

        /* Query the object type. */
        objectTypeInfo = (POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)malloc(0x1000);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(
            dupHandle,
            ObjectTypeInformation,
            objectTypeInfo,
            0x1000,
            NULL
        )))
        {
            printf("[%#x] Error!\n", handle.Handle);
            CloseHandle(dupHandle);
            continue;
        }

        /* Query the object name (unless it has an access of
           0x0012019f, on which NtQueryObject could hang. */
        if (handle.GrantedAccess == 0x0012019f)
        {
            /* We have the type, so display that. */
            printf(
                "[%#x] %.*S: (did not get name)\n",
                handle.Handle,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer
            );
            free(objectTypeInfo);
            CloseHandle(dupHandle);
            continue;
        }

        objectNameInfo = malloc(0x1000);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(
            dupHandle,
            ObjectNameInformation,
            objectNameInfo,
            0x1000,
            &returnLength
        )))
        {
            /* Reallocate the buffer and try again. */
            objectNameInfo = realloc(objectNameInfo, returnLength);
            if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtQueryObject(
                dupHandle,
                ObjectNameInformation,
                objectNameInfo,
                returnLength,
                NULL
            )))
            {
                /* We have the type name, so just display that. */
                printf(
                    "[%#x] %.*S: (could not get name)\n",
                    handle.Handle,
                    objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                    objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer
                );
                free(objectTypeInfo);
                free(objectNameInfo);
                CloseHandle(dupHandle);
                continue;
            }
        }

        /* Cast our buffer into an UNICODE_STRING. */
        objectName = *(PUNICODE_STRING)objectNameInfo;

        /* Print the information! */
        if (objectName.Length)
        {
            /* The object has a name. */
            printf(
                "[%#x] %.*S: %.*S\n",
                handle.Handle,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer,
                objectName.Length / 2,
                objectName.Buffer
            );
        }
        else
        {
            /* Print something else. */
            printf(
                "[%#x] %.*S: (unnamed)\n",
                handle.Handle,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Length / 2,
                objectTypeInfo->Name.Buffer
            );
        }

        free(objectTypeInfo);
        free(objectNameInfo);
        CloseHandle(dupHandle);
    }

    free(handleInfo);
    CloseHandle(processHandle);

    return 0;
}


Now I want to detect when another process accesses the handle of my process, but I don’t understand how this can be done.
A similar problem was solved here using C# (see comment and chat under question) - How to get notified when a new handle to my process is opened with OpenProcess from a foreign process? . As far as I understand, I need 'found all currently opened handles to your process (this already done by code up)
after this you need filter processes in 0 session. may be exporter too. another processes - probably cheat or debuggers'
I don't need kernel driver. I just want to repeat what has already been done, but using C++ directly

To get real-time notifications, you need a kernel driver, otherwise polling the system handle table is the only way (unless you inject code into every running process to hook OpenProcess() itself). What exactly have you looked at in the table to identify which items refer to your process? The table is largely undocumented (for good reason)

check my description. I add link to the stack question where it was solved but used c# win api request. I want do it but in c++ . But i don't understand comments in qustion chat. I DONT NEED KERNEL DRIVER - i need solution in UM for check if some process get handle of my process.

I did read your description. And if you pay attention to the comments on that post, this comment from @RbMm actually gave a link to C++ code that does what you are asking for
